# in return only show Instance of 'User' User is a class

Tags: flutter, list, csv, dart, instance

I want this code to convert a *csv* file to a *list*, and then convert it to *json*, for the firebase database, instead of list  this code return array it shows an instance of *class*, like this :

```
[Instance of 'User', Instance of 'User', Instance of 'User']
```

```
void main() {
 var  users= "username, email, phone \n ctavia,octavia@gmail.com, 099-83-44 \n lark, clark@gmail.com, 054-83-23 \n aven, raven@gmail.com, 784-44-98";
 var data = csvToUsersList(users);
   
      print(data); 
  
}

class User {
        String username;
        String email;
        String phone;
    
      User(this.username, this.email, this.phone);
    }


List<User> csvToUsersList(String data) {
  List<User> users = [];
  
  List<String> userin= data.split("\n");

  for (int i = 1; i < userin.length; i++) {
    List<String> user = userin[i].split(",");
    
    users.add(User(user[0], user[1], user[2]));
    
  }

  return users;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems correct. If you print something like `data.first.username`, you should get the name of the first User.

**Instance of User** just means, that this is an Object of Type User.

Comment: thanks :)
what first do in data.first.username  ?  can you explain sir

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean? :) Can you specify your question a bit more?